# how to reduce the time to list all schemas of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, schema

QGIS 3.18 PostgreSQL 14.

We use QGIS to access data from a PostGIS server. The data are stored in 33 schemas.

- one contains all the data in 17 tables;
- the others schemas contain views and materialized views created from the first schema as needed
- There are 485 objects (ordinary tables, views and materialized views)
- `autovacuum` and `track_counts` are on by default.

The "problem" is that it takes at least around 4 minutes to list all the schemas in the PostgreSQL connection window of QGIS when we want to connect to the database.
The same behaviour can be seen when using the export to PostgreSQL (available connections) plugin : after we choose the database, the list of the schemas takes a very long time to appear.
I tried to rise `shared_buffers` parameter from 128 to 256MB. I did not see any effect.

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to reduce this time ?

**EDIT:**
As requested, here is a link to the query plan : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/83d5f515345c5aa8#plan/node/354

Comment: How do you list all the schemas? Do you use a client application? Normally listing schemas means running the statement "`select * from pg_namespace` ".

Comment: Regular users use QGIS desktop to connect to the database. So they use the proper connection window from datasource manager.

Comment: Very likely the time needed doesn't come from postgres. Calling 33 schemas and 17 tables is far from being in any way resource-intensive. Try to list these from the command line of the database. This shouldn't take more than 3s under very bad conditions.

Comment: Try to measure the time exactly. If it is very close to a multiple of 30s, it is very likely a faulty timeout.

Comment: This questions seems to be about QGIS desktop, not really about PostgreSQL server.

Comment: To be specific : 33 schemas and 485 tables, views ans materialized views.

Comment: @jjanes : maybe, I try to act on all sides, and I hope one if them will be successful.

Comment: This is probably a shortcoming of QGIS. Log all statements in PostgreSQL, perform the slow operation and look at the query that is actually executed on the server. If you add that query and its `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question, we can tell you what the problem is. Perhaps that can be used to improve QGIS.

Comment: I edited the first message and post a link to the `EXPLAIN` query. The problem is a lots of seq scan on uniteobservation. "All that's left" is to try and find out why.